# Rails - Proper Model Setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, installation

I'm somewhat new to rails and am setting up my models. A certain part of my application relies on three separate models.

#### Recipe

`has_many :recipe_ingredients`

#### Recipe Ingredient

```
belongs_to :recipe
has_one :ingredient
```

#### Ingredient

`#blank right now`

Is this the proper model organization? The reason I have the recipe ingredient as a separate model is because I want to store weight and quantity values to it.

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say this is almost right. The only issue is that because RecipeIngredient `has_one` Ingredient, the ingredient record must store the recipe_ingredient_id (see [has_one association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_one-association-reference)), so a single ingredient would be bound to a recipe_ingredient (and therefore the associated recipe). This prevents you from reusing the same ingredient for different recipes.

Instead, use the following:

Recipe:

```
has_many :recipe_ingredients
has_many :ingredients, :through => :recipe_ingredients
```

RecipeIngredient:

```
belongs_to :recipe
belongs_to :ingredient
```

Ingredient:

```
has_many :recipe_ingredients
has_many :recipes, :through => recipe_ingredients
```

This establishes a many-to-many relationship between Recipes and Ingredients, so that Ingredients can be reused for multiple recipes. The quantities of each ingredient will be stored in RecipeIngredients.

Let me know if you need clarification.